# How do you invalidate a whole range in Falcor?

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

Suppose I have a simple system of categories and articles, and there's a path like this to get a list of all the articles in a specific category.

`categoriesById[{integers:ids}].articles[{ranges:rows}]`

Now, that route is hard-coded to sort the articles by newest first, so when I  add a new article, I need to (I assume) invalidate all the articles within a category because I want article `0` to be the new article.

Is there a short-hand way to invalidate the entire range of articles within a category, or do I need to invalidate every `article` under `categoriesById` explicitly, or, is there a way to splice an item into a list in the JSONGraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [range object](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/global.html#Range).

```
call(path, arg, refPaths, thisPaths) {
    // add new article
    const newLength = // get new length somehow
    return [
        {
            path: [
                "categoriesById", 
                path.categoryId, 
                "articles",
                {length: newLength}
            ],
            invalidated: true
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that you may want your `call` tu return more information about the newly created article or the updated number of articles. Here it returns nothing but the fact that the entire `articles` array must be erased from the client's cache. To return more information, you can add path/value pairs to the returned array.

Comment: Technically correct but I found I can ignore your `jsonGraph` property and I could set `invalidated: { from: 0, to: newLength }`

Comment: Sorry, still need the `jsonGraph`.

Comment: Well in theory I would think you should be able to just do `return [{path: ["users", {length: newLength}], invalidate: true}]` but that crashes for some reason.

Comment: Got it: https://github.com/Netflix/falcor/issues/789. The key changed to `invalidated` in falcor-router 0.3. I'll updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the path to the root of the collection to `invalidate`.

```
var model = new falcor.Model({
  cache: {users: [{name: "Scott"}]}
})

console.log(model.getCache().users) // Object {0: Object, length: Object}
model.invalidate("users")
console.log(model.getCache().users) // undefined
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hksyqjnu/2/)

Comment: That's interesting, but what I'm after is how the response from the router can tell the client model to do that.