# Invalidate Falcor jsonGraph fragment using jsonGraphEnvelope

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

I'm trying to invalidate a part of my jsonGraph object via the response from the falcor-router after making a CREATE call.  I can successfully do so when returning a list of [pathValues](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/global.html#PathValue), similar to [this earlier SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871885/how-do-you-invalidate-a-whole-range-in-falcor):

```
{
  route: 'foldersById[{keys:ids}].folders.createSubFolder',
  call(callPath, args, refPaths, thisPaths) {
    return createNewFolderSomehow(...)
      .subscribe(folder => {
        const folderPathValue = {
          path: ['foldersById', folder.parentId, 'folders', folder.parentSubFolderCount -1],
          value: $ref(['foldersById', folder.id])
        };

        const folderCollectionLengthPathValue = {
          path: ['folderList', 'length'],
          invalidated: true
        };

        return [folderPathValue, folderCollectionLengthPathValue];
      });
  })
}
```

However, when returning the equivalent (afaik) [jsonGraphEnvelope](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/doc/global.html#JSONGraphEnvelope), the invalidated path is dropped from the response:

```
{
  route: 'foldersById[{keys:ids}].folders.createSubFolder',
  call(callPath, args, refPaths, thisPaths) {
    return createNewFolderSomehow(...)
      .subscribe(folder => {
        const newFolderPath = ['foldersById', folder.parentId, 'folders', folder.parentSubFolderCount -1];
        return {
          jsonGraph: R.assocPath(folderPath, $ref(['foldersById', folder.id]), {})
          paths: [newFolderPath],
          invalidated: [['folderList', 'length']]
        };
      });
  })
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how a jsonGraphEnvelope works (had assumed it was a longhand format equivalent to an array of PathValues)?  Or is this likely a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me.

Invalidations don't seem to be handled in the part of the code responsible for merging partial JSONGraph envelopes returned from routes into the JSONGraph envelope response (see [here](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router/blob/master/src/cache/jsongMerge.js)), while they are handled in the path-value merge (see [here](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router/blob/master/src/cache/pathValueMerge.js)).

I can't find any issue about this on [GitHub](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router/issues) so I invite you to open one.

Comment: Posted [issue](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router/issues/192) to github.  Thanks for linking to the relevant code--might fork and try to patch locally.